# how to get html table tr cell value by javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML table created with dynamic data and cannot predict the number of rows in it. What I want to do is to get the value of a row cells when the last cell of a specific row is clicked.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'value of a row'?  The index?  The data that was used to create it?

Comment: can you show us the output of the dynamically generated table? Also where is the table being generated on front or back end?

Comment: put your HTML code here

Comment: @PiyushYadav you should use jQuery find function for this

Answer (score 0):

Use a counter variable to calculate the row number.

Comment: how it possible ?? can you tell me I don't think so it has possible using counter

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery for brevity and compatibility:

```
$('tr').on('click', function(evt){
    console.log(this);
});
```

That gives you the DOM object you just clicked on.  If you only want the last TD to fire the event (assuming you have 4 columns), it might look more like this:

```
$('tr td:nth-child(4)').on('click', function(evt){
    console.log($(this).parent());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So first get the element using getElementByID etc, then you can get the actual content of that row by **element.innerHTML**

```js
  var tableRow = document.getElementById("tr3");
var content = tableRow.innerHTML;
alert(content);
```

```css
table td {border: 1px solid black;}
```

```html
    <table>
      <tr id="tr1"><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
      <tr id="tr2"><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
      <tr id="tr3"><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
</table>
```

you can use an onClick function to get the value.